# zend framework stringtrim filter not working

Tags: zend-framework, filter

I'm having trouble with zend framework's string trim filter. I use the following code to set up a text element in a Zend_Form:

```
$voucherValidator = new Project_Validate_Voucher();        
$code = $this->addElement('text', 'code', array('label'=>'Gutscheincode'));
$code = $this->getElement('code')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
    ->addValidator($voucherValidator, true);
```

When I type in some text with preceeding blanks or tabs, the validator correctly works on the StringTrim filtered input and accepts the input. When I later check the $_POST['code'] after code submission, I get the unfiltered input. How can I get my text element to post the filtered value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use $code = $this->code->getValue() as Zend_Form doesn't actually filter the $_POST array.

Comment: Awesome, this works :). Btw, I found out that I can also use $this->getValue('code'). Thanks a lot

Comment: You can also use this getValues() and that will return the whole form filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i know i'm late but in case any one faced the same problem,

I have faced this problem today and i found few ways to solve this problem:

i have answered same reply on this post 
[Other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42736214/2918720)

first my code is:

- This is the **form** class

  class Application_Form_UserForm extends Zend_Form
    {

  public function init()
     {

  ```
  /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
  $this->setMethod('POST');

  $fname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('fname');
  $fname->setLabel('First Name: ');
  $fname->setAttribs(Array(
      'placeholder'=>'Example: Eslam',
      'class'=>'form-control'
  ));
  $fname->setRequired();
  $fname->addValidator('StringLength', false, Array(4,20));
  $fname->addFilter('StringTrim');
  $fname->addFilter('StripTags');
  $fname->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
  $fname->removeDecorator('label');
  $fname->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');


  $lname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('lname');
  $lname->setLabel('Last Name: ');
  $lname->setAttribs(Array(
      'placeholder'=>'Example: Khoga',
      'class'=>'form-control'
  ));
  $lname->setRequired();
  $lname->addValidator('StringLength', false, Array(4,20));
  $lname->addFilter('StringTrim');
  $lname->addFilter('StripTags');
  $lname->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
  $lname->removeDecorator('label');
  $lname->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');

  $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
  $email->setLabel('Email: ');
  $email->setAttribs(Array(
      'placeholder'=>'Example@Example.com',
      'class'=>'form-control'
  ));
  $email->setRequired();
  $email->addValidator('StringLength', false, Array(5,250));
  $email->addFilter('StringTrim');
  $email->addFilter('StripTags');
  $email->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
  $email->removeDecorator('label');
  $email->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');

  $gender = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('gender');
  $gender->setRequired();
  $gender->addMultiOption('male','Male')->
  addMultiOption('female','Female')->
  addMultiOption('none','Prefer not to mention');
  $gender->setAttrib('class', 'form-control');


  $track_obj = new Application_Model_Track();
  $allTracks = $track_obj->listAll();
  $track = new Zend_Form_element_Select('track');
  foreach($allTracks as $key=>$value)
  {
      $track->addMultiOption($value['id'], $value['name']);
  }

  $submit= new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
  $submit->setAttribs(array('class'=>'btn btn-success'));

  $reset= new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('reset');
  $reset->setAttribs(array('class'=>'btn btn-danger'));

  $this->addElements(array(
      $fname,
      $lname,
      $email,
      $gender,
      $track,
      $submit,
      $reset
  ));
  ```

  }

  }
- This is **controller** class

class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action{

```
public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
}

public function listAction()
{
    // action body
    $user_model = new Application_Model_User();
    $this->view->users = $user_model->listUsers();

    $track_form = new Application_Form_Track();
    $this->view->track_form = $track_form;
    $track_model = new Application_Model_Track();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if($request->isPost())
    {
        if($track_form->isValid($request->getPost())){
            $track_model-> addTrack($request->getParams());
            $this->redirect('/user/add');
        }
    }
}

public function detailsAction()
{
    // action body
    $user_model = new Application_Model_User();
    $us_id = $this->_request->getParam("uid");
    $user = $user_model->userDetails($us_id);
    $trackModel = new Application_Model_Track();
    $track = $trackModel->getTrackName($user[0]['track']);
    $user[0]['track'] = $track[0]['name'];
    $this->view->user = $user[0];
}

public function deleteAction()
{
    // action body
    $user_model = new Application_Model_User();
    $us_id = $this->_request->getParam("uid");
    $user_model->deleteUser($us_id);
    $this->redirect("/user/list");
}

public function addAction()
{
    // action body
    $form = new Application_Form_UserForm();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if($request->isPost()){
        if($form->isValid($request->getPost())){
            /*echo "<pre>";
            print_r($form);
            echo "</pre>";
            exit;*/
            $userData['fname'] = $form->getValue('fname');
            $userData['lname'] = $form->getValue('lname');
            $userData['email'] = $form->getValue('email');
            $userData['gender'] = $form->getValue('gender');
            $userData['track'] = $form->getValue('track');
            $user_model = new Application_Model_User();
            $user_model-> addNewUser($userData);
            $this->redirect('/user/list');
        }
    }
    $this->view->user_form = $form;
}

public function editAction()
{
    // action body
    $form = new Application_Form_UserForm();
    $user_model = new Application_Model_User ();
    $id = $this->_request->getParam('uid');
    $user_data = $user_model-> userDetails($id)[0];
    $form->populate($user_data);
    $this->view->userName = $user_data['fname']." ".$user_data['lname'];
    $this->view->user_form = $form;
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if($request->isPost()){
        if($form->isValid($request->getPost())){
            $userData['fname'] = $form->getValue('fname');
            $userData['lname'] = $form->getValue('lname');
            $userData['email'] = $form->getValue('email');
            $userData['gender'] = $form->getValue('gender');
            $userData['track'] = $form->getValue('track');
            $user_model-> updateUser($id, $userData);
            $this->redirect('/user/list');
        }
    }
}


}
```

**First Solution:**

i used filter on **Form elements** in the form class,
but i retrieved data from **$form** object in the controller,
as i found that method

> addFilter()

doesn't change in the $_POST array values, so i have retrieved the data from $form object and then passed it as array to Model.

**Second Solution:**

i have tried to apply the filter on the values in the controller, not in the form by creating object from filter class and apply needed filter

**Third Solution:**

is to use method

> addValidator()

with *regex* which affects on $_POST values.